# Finding mesh elements within a given region

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, intersection

I write a code that generates the following mesh. I would like to find out the elements that completely lie within a certain circular region inside this meshed area. How do I do that?

[image]

The code that I wrote is shown below:

```
w=100; (* Box width *)
h=100; (* Box height *)
xmin = 0; 
ymin = 0; 
xmax = xmin + w; 
ymax = ymin + h;
d = 10;(* Mesh Size *)

<< NDSolve`FEM`
(* Create the coordinates *)
coords = {};(* Nodal Coordinate Matrix *)
nx = w/d + 1;(* Number of nodes in the x-direction *)
ny = h/d + 1;(* Number of nodes in the y-direction *)
For[i = 0, 
 i <= nx - 1, i++,
 For[j = 0, j <= ny - 1, j++,
  coords = Append[coords, {xmin + i*d, ymin + j*d}]; 
  ]
 ]

(* Create Element Connectivity Matrix to generate triangular elements *)
elMat = {};(* Element Connectivity Matrix *)
For[i = 1, 
 i <= ny - 1, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= nx - 1, j++,
  elMat = 
   Append[elMat, {(i - 1)*ny + j, (i - 1)*ny + j + 1, i*ny + j}];
  elMat = Append[elMat, {i*ny + j, i*ny + j + 1, (i - 1)*ny + j + 1}]
  ]
 ]

(* Create Mesh *)
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[elMat]}];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

Answer (score 6):

The following looks for coordinates the lie within 20 unit radius of the point {50,50}:

```
elmcrd = GetElementCoordinates[mesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]];
mf = RegionMember[Disk[{50, 50}, 20]];
caf = ContainsAll[{True, True, True}];
PositionIndex[caf /@ Flatten[mf /@ elmcrd, 1]]
(* <|False -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
   15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
    32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 
   48, 49, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
    75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 
   102, 103, 104, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
   126, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
   146, 147, 148, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 
   162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 
   175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 
   188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200}, 
 True -> {50, 51, 52, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 
   91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
   113, 114, 115, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 149, 150, 151}|> *)
```

You should note that the ordering of your triangles gives you a negative mesh quality.  You should consider re-ordering the triangle elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily with [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package.

```
Get["MeshTools`"]

mesh = QuadToTriangleMesh@RectangleMesh[{0, 0}, {100, 100}, {10, 10}]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh_rectangle]

```
reg = Disk[{50, 50}, 40];
selected = SelectElements[mesh, RegionMember[reg][{#1, #2}] &]

Show[
 selected["Wireframe"],
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], reg}]
]
```

[image: mesh_disk]

Comment: good to see you ;-)

Comment: This works very well. I have an additional question: Right now, each quad element is split into 2 triangles. Is it possible to split each quad element into 4 triangular elements? Put another way, is it possible to split each quad element using both its diagonals?

Comment: "MeshTools" pacakge doesn't have such option implemented. But of course, splitting triangles again is possible, but you have to write the function yourself.